# Do I need to include this line: <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Do I need this line for google analytics? I'm minifying my html and it's removing the line. I can't find much on google about this.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
```

The rest of the code is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is a comment and won't affect functionality!

Comments in HTML begin with `<!--` and end with `-->` Anything between those, won't run or render.